# How to use Solve properly

Tags: equation-solving

I'm attempting to solve the following system of equations for k and $\kappa$ $$\mu\epsilon\omega^2=k^2-\kappa^2$$ $$\mu\sigma\omega=2k\kappa$$ but when I type into Mathematica

```
Simplify[Solve[{μ ϵ ω^2 == k^2 - κ^2, μ σ ω == 2 k κ}, {k, κ}]
```

I get the following output, which is pretty gnarly

[image]

The solution I was hoping to get (from a textbook) is 
$$k\equiv \omega\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon\mu}{2}}\left[\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon\omega}\right)^2}+1\right]^{1/2}$$
$$\kappa\equiv \omega\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon\mu}{2}}\left[\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon\omega}\right)^2}-1\right]^{1/2}$$
I'm not sure how to simplify the output from Mathematica to get it into that specific from I'm looking for. Are there extra assumptions I need to pass? I've tried the same command as Simplify only changing it to Reduce but it's still not quite clear the direction to take. For some context, this is looking at the complex wave number from Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics.

Comment: Would I use `PowerExpand` before or after `Solve`?

Comment: Actually, in `Simplify` you can use `Assumptions` like this: `sol = Solve[{μ ϵ ω^2 == k^2 - κ^2, μ σ ω == 2 k κ}, {k, κ}]; Simplify[sol, Assumptions -> {μ > 0, ϵ > 0, ω > 0}]`. And then select the solution you need, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Simplify[
 Solve[Eliminate[{μ ϵ ω^2 == k^2 - κ^2, μ σ ω == 2 k κ}, κ], k], 
 {ω > 0, σ > 0, ϵ > 0, μ > 0}
 ]
```

yielding the results for k

[image]

The last two results look almost like you want. To bring them exactly to the needed form try this:

```
expr = Sqrt[μ ω (ϵ ω + 
     Sqrt[ σ^2 + ϵ^2 ω^2])]/Sqrt[2];

HoldForm[ω*Sqrt[(ϵ*μ)/2]]* Simplify[
   Expand[expr/(ω*Sqrt[(ϵ*μ)/2])], 
   {ω > 0, σ > 0, ϵ > 0, μ > 0}
   ] // ReleaseHold
```

returning the following:

[image]

The same you could do for kappa.

Have fun!

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Henrik, what do you do to introduce the Greek letters into the code?

Comment: I installed NinjaKit and halirutan's script https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044. Should you use Safari as browser, you have to activate Extension Builders manually after each relaunch of the browser (which is annoying). Anyways, you get these very neat buttons that allow you to perform many replacements of `\[...]`-syntax to unicode symbols at once. Have a try!

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch So I used the last expression you have beginning with `HoldForm` but got the same output as before with no change. Are there some preferences I need to change in order to get what you have? I have Mathematica 11.3 if that helps.

Comment: Maybe you used as the expression, not the same as I did? Have a look, I edited the answer.

Comment: That was it, I didn't have the expr in there.